# Variable value inside XML tag

Tags: php, xml

I want to put the value of $album into an XML tag called category. But everything I try is wrong. The closest I get is the variable name $album but not the data inside. I'm new to writing XML with php. I have tried all sorts of concatenation & have seen CDATA mentioned here but don't know if I should be using it or how.

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "user";
$dbpass = "password";
$dbname = "db";
@mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM responsivegallery_rgal";
$q   = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$album = $q['album_rgal'];
$category_tag = '"<category caption = ". $album .">"';

$xml = "<gallery>";
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){


  $xml .= $category_tag ."</category>";
  $xml .= "<item>"; 
  $xml .= "<image>"."gallery_files/slides/".$r['image_rgal']."</image>";
  $xml .= "<thumb>"."gallery_files/slides/".$r['thumb_rgal']."</thumb>";  
  $xml .= "<caption>".$r['title_rgal']."</caption>";
  $xml .= "</item>";  
}
$xml .= "</gallery>";
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->asXML("test.xml");
//$sxe->asXML("../gallery_files/gallery.xml");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You constructing your loop incorrectly, the `$q` wasn't fetched so `['album_rgal']` won't exist. Try this

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "user";
$dbpass = "password";
$dbname = "db";
@mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM responsivegallery_rgal";
$q   = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$xml = "<gallery>";
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
  $xml .= '<category caption="'. $r['album_rgal'] .'"></category>';
  $xml .= "<item>";
  $xml .= "<image>"."gallery_files/slides/".$r['image_rgal']."</image>";
  $xml .= "<thumb>"."gallery_files/slides/".$r['thumb_rgal']."</thumb>";  
  $xml .= "<caption>".$r['title_rgal']."</caption>";
  $xml .= "</item>";  
}
$xml .= "</gallery>";
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->asXML("test.xml");
//$sxe->asXML("../gallery_files/gallery.xml");
?>
```

Also your concatenation was off.

```
$category_tag = '"<category caption = ". $album .">"';
```

would have been

```
$category_tag = '"<category caption = "'. $album .'">"';
```

Comment: That worked! Brilliant. Hope I'm allowed to ask a bit more. The opening category tag has a closing forward slash in it at the end but the slash is not in the code. Also how can I get the category tag to only show once. Example would be if I had 20 images I only want category to show the one time not 20 times or in other words not on each loop. I think it may be a sql problem, am I correct? Or is it the structure of the XML output?

Comment: I fixed the closing slash issue in the category opening tag by moving the closing `</category>`  tag to the bottom under the closing `</item>` tag. Still can't get my head around how to select just one album id to go with the corresponding images & thumbs. They are all in the same table

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean when working with the XML later or on this page? On this page you could update your query so you only get the photos from one album, `SELECT * FROM responsivegallery_rgal where album_rgal = 1` or something, or you could order by `album_rgal` then they'd all be in order. Also why was the closing slash breaking it?